# How can I measure distance travelled in cm without gps?

Tags: distance

I was asked to build a circuit that will measure the distance travelled of a small vehicle, like a lawn mower.

There's a requirement that it would measure distance travelled in cm/sec. GPS is too inaccurate, and the starting point is unknown. I'm unable to put anything in the ground.

Any ideas? I can use whatever IC I want. I thought of using a camera pointing down, like a mouse, but it seems too complicated to process outside of home.

Comment: If it has wheels that make reliable contact with the ground a quadrature encoder would work, is that the case so you really just need to measure how far the wheels rotate?

Comment: A lot of companies would like to come up with the answer to that question.

Comment: I suggest that you review [Dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning). The use of accelerometer (speed measurement), and magnetometers (direction) might mostly do the job for you. Looks like your system has a wheel. So a wheel speed sensor can also assisting acquiring additional infomation make your system accurate. Also look at [irobot](http://www.irobot.com/For-the-Home/Vacuum-Cleaning/Roomba.aspx) The hardware to the most part is open source. This should help you with some ideas

Comment: "measure distance travelled in cm/sec"?? distance can be in cm, cm/sec is speed, not distance. Try to be more precise in the formulation fo your question.

Comment: Have a look at the DARPA vehicle challenge; some entries successfully used the "optical mouse" technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the small vehicle is like a lawn mower I am assuming the small vehicle has wheels. You have many options to choose from based on your requirements.

- As [PeterJ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17064/peterj) suggested you can use a quadrature encoder.
- Another option is use and Hall effect sensor. This type of application is used frequently in automotive applications.
- The use of an accelerometer will enable speed measurements. Consider a three axis accelerometer, thus this will infomation as as to if the vehicle going up an incline or down an incline. I create a simple accelerometer demo using Beaglebone black, Embedded QT and ADXL345 which can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQtwIwBGoVChMI8OnV_KvlxgIVw9GACh0nogZn&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dbd7ULY1frA4&ei=dJ-qVfDfFsOjgwSnxJq4Bg&usg=AFQjCNFALAyQHqdWfSe1oPOMyDfnVqvXdw&sig2=hsyZuOTRKCcF8Lxt1xV7nA). The source is available to public on github. I also did similar demo using TIVA ARM Cortex M4 + ADXL345. I can make the source code pubic if interested.
- The use of a magnetometers will help determine direction in XY direction

Also take a look at the [Dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) concept. Dead reckoning doesn't use GPS, and is widely used in automotive navigation applications when GPS is not present, such as driving through a tunnel.

Another interesting application is [irobot create](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2.aspx). As I understand the both hardware and software is open sourced. This will give some good ideas for your project. Below is picture of guts of iRobot command module.

[image]

Another option would to use myRio from NI. Although the hardware is not open source myRio allows you the connect to LabView to help develop algorithms.

**References:**

- [Dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning)
- [NI myRIO](http://www.ni.com/myrio/)
- [iRobot Command Module](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAAahUKEwjvtYTAmuXGAhVG0YAKHaVGCg4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.irobot.com%2Ffilelibrary%2Fpdfs%2Fhrd%2Fcreate%2FCommand%2520Module%2520Manual_v2.pdf&ei=IY2qVa-hMcaigwSljalw&usg=AFQjCNEYTDUuFuBGo84__qVsNjjkduW7Pg&sig2=LAh_rpRBohha-Fr2YhHCzA&bvm=bv.98197061,d.cWw)
- [BeagleboneBlack_ADXL345_GUI](https://github.com/mahengunawardena/BeagleboneBlack_ADXL345_GUI)
- [Cyber-Physical Systems form University of California at Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/cyber-physical-systems-uc-berkeleyx-eecs149-1x)
- [Mounting and Coupling an Encoder](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/452/mounting-and-coupling-an-encoder)
- [The Benefits of GPS](http://www.njtc.org/technews-july-august-2015/#2)